# Unable to extract Email addresses from Pop Up

Tags: selenium, web, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I have problem. I am trying to extract the email addresses from a website.

[image]

When trying to extract the email addresses,I have to click on the email icon enter image description here in order for it to appear. Once I click on the icon, a new "popup" appears.

[image]

I have tried using Selenium get_attribute for data-mailto-token & data-mailto-vector enter image description here, but without any success. How can I extract the email addresses with Python from these so called "popups"? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Kind regards

Linus

I have tried using Selenium and looked into to further libraries for cross plattform access, but without any success

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException, NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementClickInterceptedException
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re


#card_small = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("Card small")

i_num = 1

list_links = []

list_links_all = []

num_inc = 1

for i_p in range(0,14):

    url = "https://www.hotelleriesuisse.ch/de/branche-und-politik/branchenverzeichnis/hotel-page-"+str(num_inc)+"?filterValues=QWN0aXZlLEluYWN0aXZlOzs7OzQsMzs7Ozs7OzQ5LDEzLDUsNDU7&cHash=30901b0e3080a928cd0ad32522e81b3f"
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    driver.get(url)

    time.sleep(5)


    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("body > div.cc-window.cc-banner.cc-type-info.cc-theme-block.cc-bottom.cc-visible > div > div.cc-actions > a.cc-btn.cc-allow").click()

    try:
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,2150)")

        target = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")

        for i in target:
            list_links.append(i.get_attribute("href"))

        for i in range(10,22):
            url_new = list_links[i]
            print(url_new)
            headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}
            page = requests.get(url_new, headers=headers)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

            name = soup.find('span',class_="Avatar--name")
            address = soup.find_all('span', class_="Button--label")
            phone = soup.find_all('span', class_="Button--label")


            if name != None:
                name_text = soup.find('span', class_="Avatar--name").text
                #print(name_text)

            if address != None:
                for i in address:
                    search=i.select("span p")
                    if search != []:
                        print(search[0].text)
            if phone != None:
                for i in phone:
                    match = re.search("[+]\d{2} \d{2} \d{3} \d{2} \d{2}",i.text)
                    if match !=None:
                        print(match.group())
            time.sleep(5)

            driver.get(url_new)

            try:

                driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,900)")

                time.sleep(5)

                element=driver.find_element_by_link_text("E-Mail")

                info = element.get_attribute("data-mailto-token")

                print(info)

                element.click()



            except NoSuchElementException:
                pass




        list_links = []
        num_inc = num_inc + 1
        i_num = i_num + 1

        driver.close()

        """
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#main-content > section.CardGrid > nav > a.Button.nolabel.primary.Pagination--button.Pagination--next").click()
        time.sleep(5)
        print("This is the end of page: "+str(i_num))
        i_num = i_num + 1
        time.sleep(5)
        """
    except ElementClickInterceptedException:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

The email address can be obtained by decrypting the combination of data-mailto-token and data-mailto-vector values found in the button.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I am not quite sure, how I would go on about this in Python. Would it be possible for you to attach some code, so that I can learn from it? Would this library: https://pyjwt.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ lead me to the desired result?

Comment: If you look at the link element representing the e-mail button using DevTools then you will see (on the Event Listeners tab) that there is a click event.  Following this, to its location in default_frontend.js, and placing a breakpoint there will enable you to see exactly what actions are being carried out.

Comment: Did that not help?  The email is generated via a call to: _decryptString(dataset.mailtoToken, parseInt(dataset.mailtoVector, 10) * -1)_ with the decrypt function being defined on line 46 of the same js file.

Comment: First of all, I really appreciate your help. Yes, I looked through it now and understand the general concept behind it, but I am a little confused as of how I can implement it into my python code.

Comment: You will first need to implement the decryptString function in Python.  Then you can retrieve the token and vector values from the link and pass them through the local function  rather than clicking on the link.